# Pronunciation of berk and Berkshire

Tags: british-english, slang, pronunciation-vs-spelling

When I was young (1950's southern England) I learned that Berkshire, pronounced "BARK-sheer" was a county the other side of London, and that a "berk", pronounced to rhyme with "work" or "jerk", was a deplorable individual. Later I learned that "berk" is rhyming slang for "Berkshire Hunt", thus "c*nt".

But they don't rhyme in my pronunciation! How did this come about? Is it subsequent spelling pull on "berk", did Cockneys at the time say "BERK-sheer", or something else?

EDIT made it clear that I never thought that "berk" and "jerk" were regarded as rhyming slang.

Comment: Where did you read that the rhyming slang involved "berk" rhyming with "jerk"?  If you can provide a source that would help with an answer.  The sources I've found suggest that "Berk," short for "Berkshire Hunt" is a shortened rhyme slang for "cunt," but make no mention of "Berk" being rhyming slang for "jerk."

Comment: Sorry @RaceYouAnyTime that was sloppy writing on my part. "Jerk" was an unfortunate pronunciation example. Question (I hope) clarified.

Comment: Just because *Berkshire* is pronounced "Bark-" in RP or Standard English does not mean that it's pronounced that way in every dialect, including Cockney.

Comment: I no longer try to understand why certain place names are pronounced the way they are in English. After Worcestershire I gave up.

Comment: @AndrewLeach the name of the county of Derby is pronounced 'Darbyshire' in SP but 'Derbyshir' in most Derbyshire dialects. Another good example perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/berk#Pronunciation) explains:

> In both Berkeley and Berkshire, berk is pronounced in RP like bark (IPA(key): /bɑː(ɹ)k/). In other cases such as Cockney and American English pronunciation, it rhymes with work.